# Iterate Dataframe using list and groupby

Tags: python, list, pandas

I have a Dataframe that I'd like to perform the same operation (ie, correlations, graphing) on grouped data. The grouping is based on location (refered to as STA in the Dataframe).

Sample of the Dataframe is below:

```
Index STA   Date        Var1    Var2    Var3   
0   RE25    1973-04-09  1.0     10.5    6.3
1   RE30    1973-04-09  1.0     10.0    7.6
2   RE25    1973-04-09  5.0     10.6    NaN
3   RE30    1973-04-09  5.0     10.0    NaN
4   RE25    1973-04-09  10.0    10.6    NaN
5   RE30    1973-04-09  10.0    10.2    NaN
6   RE25    1973-04-09  15.0    10.7    NaN
7   RE30    1973-04-09  15.0    10.1    NaN
8   RE25    1973-04-09  20.0    10.7    NaN
9   RE30    1973-04-09  20.0    10.1    NaN
10  RE30    1973-04-09  23.0    10.0    7.6
```

To generate the list of unique sampling STA (which will be different for each DataFrame), I used

`Stations = np.sort(Resdat.STA.unique()).tolist()`

which works in creating the unique list of STA that I'm after. However, when I try to call this list I get the following error:

`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable.`

With my limited knowledge, I'm only making progress with the following code:

`RE01 = Resdat.groupby('STA').get_group('RE01')

RE01 = RE01.dropna(axis = 1, how = 'all')`

repeated over and over for each unique STA.

I'm sure there is a better way but I'm struggling to find other posted answers that I can use.

Comment: What does "However, when I try to call this list..." mean? What do you are you trying to do when you call a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using for loop

```
names=[]
l=[]
for name, data in df.groupby('STA'):
    names.append(name)
    l.append(data.dropna(axis=1, how='all'))
```

Comment: Sorry - I haven't been able to try this yet. Could you explain what the code is doing?

Comment: @Newstudent14 this split your df by STA, and doing the dropna  of the subset , restore the result into a list , if you want to combine it back to a dataframe doing pd.concate(l)